# How to get max value of a column using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, max

To get maximum value of a column that contains integer, I can use the following T-SQL comand

```
SELECT MAX(expression )
FROM tables
WHERE predicates;
```

Is it possible to obtain the same result with Entity Framework.

Let's say I have the following model

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonID { get; set; }
  public int Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the oldest person's age?

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.?
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Try this `int maxAge = context.Persons.Max(p => p.Age);`

And make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file

Comment: I strugled a bit with this because I missed the "using System.Linq;"
You should consider adding that info to your answer to newbies like me :)

Comment: No problem @RagnaRock

Comment: But what if you don't have any records and EF trows errors. My addition var model = db.BillOfLading.Select(x => x.No).LastOrDefault();
   if (model != null)
   {
    var val = db.BillOfLading.Max(x => x.No);

Comment: Is this efficient? Or would it be better to have entity framework execute a stored procedure that uses the Max function? New to entity framework and am genuinely curious

Comment: @Programmatic absolutely no reason that would be more efficient. Except on Sql Server version <= 7.

Comment: Even with `using System.Linq`, in `Web API` I get the intellisense error "the name 'context' does not exist in the current context. Is it correct that this should go in the controller? I'm trying to put it inside one of my CRUD methods, but have also tried other areas in the controller to no avail :(

Comment: @KyleVassella - your web API's data context variable may be named differently. If you scaffolded your API controller using Visual Studio built-in defaults, the API controllers have a single `db` field (which is the EF data context) for the whole class, and within the body of any of your methods you can access it directly. 

When the web request is over, there are scaffolded Dispose methods that take care of cleaning up the `db` variable.

Comment: Good for async in EF Core: await _context.Persons.MaxAsync(x => (int?)x.Age) ?? 0

Answer (score 75):

If the list is empty I get an exception. This solution will take into account this issue:

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Select(p => p.Age).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Only one round-trip to the server and no exceptions.

Comment: But it retrieves all column values from the database, and applies Max on the application side.

Comment: This makes 3 sub-queries. I proposed a different answer.

Comment: just a side note - this doesn't work with EF core. I used: `await _context.Persons.MaxAsync(x => (int?)x.Age) ?? 0`

Answer (score 16):

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Max(p => p.Age);
```

The version above, **if the list is empty**:

- Returns `null` ― for nullable overloads
- Throws `Sequence contains no element` exception ― for non-nullable overloads

_

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Select(p => p.Age).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

The version above handles the empty list case, but it generates more complex query, and for some reason doesn't work with EF Core.

_

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Max(p => (int?)p.Age) ?? 0;
```

This version is **elegant** and **performant** (simple query and single round-trip to the database), **works with EF Core**. It handles the mentioned exception above by casting the non-nullable type to nullable and then applying the default value using the `??` operator.

Comment: using `context.Persons.Max(p => (int?)p.Age) ?? 0` work fine in ef core 5.0, and for some reason this one `context.Persons.Select(p => p.Age).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()` cannot be translated, so ef core 5.0 throw an exception.

Comment: This `context.Persons.Select(p => p.Age).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()` one also does not with EF Core 3.0 and I used the `context.Persons.Max(p => (int?)p.Age) ?? 0`.

Answer (score 13):

Or you can try this:

```
(From p In context.Persons Select p Order By age Descending).FirstOrDefault
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe help, if you want to add some filter:

```
context.Persons
.Where(c => c.state == myState)
.Select(c => c.age)
.DefaultIfEmpty(0)
.Max();
```

Answer (score 8):

**Your column is nullable**

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Select(p => p.Age).Max() ?? 0;
```

**Your column is non-nullable**

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Select(p => p.Age).Cast<int?>().Max() ?? 0;
```

In both cases, you can use the second code. If you use `DefaultIfEmpty`, you will do a bigger query on your server. For people who are interested, here are the EF6 equivalent:

**Query without `DefaultIfEmpty`**

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        MAX([Extent1].[Age]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

**Query with `DefaultIfEmpty`**

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        MAX([Join1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ([Project1].[C1] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project1].[Age] END AS [A1]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], 
                cast(1 as tinyint) AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [Extent1]) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
        )  AS [Join1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: What about `int maxAge = context.Persons.Max(x => (int?)x.Age) ?? 0;`

Answer (score 5):

```
maxAge = Persons.Max(c => c.age)
```

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 5):

As many said - this version

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Max(p => p.Age);
```

throws an exception when table is empty.

Use

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Max(x => (int?)x.Age) ?? 0;
```

or

```
int maxAge = context.Persons.Select(x => x.Age).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()
```

Comment: your second answer looks good to me, if someone look at generated SQL, 2nd answer is good.

Answer (score 5):

Selected answer throws exceptions, and the answer from Carlos Toledo applies filtering after retrieving all values from the database.

The following one runs a single round-trip and reads a single value, using any possible indexes, without an exception.

```
int maxAge = _dbContext.Persons
  .OrderByDescending(p => p.Age)
  .Select(p => p.Age)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: When dealing with inner joins and where clauses, this produces the fastest and cleanest SQL.

Answer (score 2):

In **VB.Net** it would be

```
Dim maxAge As Integer = context.Persons.Max(Function(p) p.Age)
```