# How to return max value by asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this query:

Select MAX(CAST(value As int)) from tableName

I want to get the max value of a column using entity formwork and put it on the corner of my website.

Comment: This question have already been answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542021/how-to-get-max-value-of-a-column-using-entity-framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get max value of a column using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542021/how-to-get-max-value-of-a-column-using-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Max()` method. Also use lambda expressions:

```
var max = context.TableName.Max(i => i.ColumnName);
```

(Where ColumnName is the column what you aggregate on.)