# How to get the Max from column - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I need get the Max from column using Entity Framework without use GroupBy.

```
var query= from r in table1
           join rt in table2 on r.ID equals rt.ID
           where rt.DateStart >= dtS && rt.DateEnd < dtE
           select new datart { ID = rt.ID, Start = rt.DateStart, End = rt.DateEnd }
```

I want make something like this:

```
 var query= from r in table1
               join rt in table2 on r.ID equals rt.ID
               where rt.DateStart >= dtS && rt.DateEnd < dtE
               select new datart { ID = rt.ID, Start = Min.(rt.DateStart), End = Max.(rt.DateEnd) }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get max value of a column using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542021/how-to-get-max-value-of-a-column-using-entity-framework)

Comment: No, in my cause i make one query

Comment: Why are you using JOINs at all? An ORMs job is to map tables to objects so you don't have to manually do so. There are no tables in an ORM. If your *entities* had proper relations you could write a very simple query. Eg if a `Customer` has an `Orders` property, EF Core will generate the `Customer inner join Orders` clause when you try to load properties from both.

Comment: With proper entities and relations, if you wanted to find the customer for the latest order you could write `ctx.Orders.OrderByDescending(o=>o.DateStart).Select(o=> new {o.Customer.ID,Start=o.DateStart})`. EF Core would generate `SELECT TOP 1 c.ID,o.DateStart From Customers c inner join Orders o on c.ID=o.CustomerID Order By o.DateStart DESC`

Comment: If you want something else - what do you actually want? What are `r` and `rt`? And if you want to show min and max dates, where would `ID` come from? Are you trying to get min and max dated by ID? In that case you need `group by into` or the `GroupBy` method

Comment: `r.ID = r.rt.ID` ? Is this a typo?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i try like you say, but i get less results then i try without group by. So, i try , get min and max dated by id in Select .

Comment: You still haven't explained what you want to do. At least post some sample data and expected results. If you return only `rt` properties, why are you using a JOIN? And once again, you can't return both an `ID` and min/max values in SQL. Not just EF Core, but SQL, the language itself. If `ID` is the primary key, there's only a single row

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question, but I guess using [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) + [First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0) can help you:

```cs
var query= from r in table1
           join rt in table2 on r.ID = r.rt.ID
           where rt.DateStart >= dtS && rt.DateEnd < dtE
           select new datart { ID = rt.ID, Start = rt.DateStart };

var result =
    query
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.DateStart)
    .First();
```

Comment: Is not possible make this OrderByDescending / First in query?

Comment: Yes it is, but your query shows a misuse of EF Core. If you used proper objects and relations you could write `ctx.Orders.OrderByDescending(o=>o.DateStart).Select(o=> new {o.Customer.ID,Start=o.DateStart})`

Comment: @JoséMarquês, you can enclose query expression in parentheses and then call both methods. Any case only one SQL is executed.

Comment: @daniherrera  or Panagiotis 
Can you show one example?

Comment: Just a side note: `.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateStart).First()` as it currently stands could be replaced by `.MaxBy(t => t.DateStart)`

Comment: @AstridE. we don't know what the OP wants, as the queries are full of typos and errors. Perhaps they want the parent row corresponding to the latest detail? Eg, the customer of the latest order? That would need `TOP 1/ORDER BY Desc`. The latest detail date? No need for joins then, just `ctx.Details.Max(d=>d.DateStart)`. Max/min dates for the parent?

Comment: @AstridE. I don't believe `MaxBy` is supported for SQL translation in EF core (at least with the default drivers for SQL Server).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True. I was commenting in the context of this specific answer, though, addressing the use of `.OrderByDescending( ).First()` and how that may be simplified.

Comment: @KirkWoll Ah, my bad. Thank you for pointing that out.